# C# HTML Parse of web page

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I am attempting to parse a html web page to get information from it. Here is a sample of the source:

```
<div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row listing_2107979855708535333" id="listing_2107979855708535333">

<div class="market_listing_item_img_container">     <img id="listing_2107979855708535333_image" src="asdgfasdfgasgasgdasgasdgsdasgsadg" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" />    </div>
        <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_action_buttons">
                <div class="market_listing_buy_button">
                            <a href="javascript:BuyMarketListing('listing', '2107979855708535333', 570, '2', '508690045')" class="item_market_action_button item_market_action_button_green">
                <span class="item_market_action_button_edge item_market_action_button_left"></span>
                <span class="item_market_action_button_contents">
                    Buy Now                 </span>
                <span class="item_market_action_button_edge item_market_action_button_right"></span>
                <span class="item_market_action_button_preload"></span>
            </a>
                        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
    <span>
                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
            0,03 p&#1091;&#1073;.           </span>
        <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
            0,01 p&#1091;&#1073;.           </span>
        <br/>
                </span>
```

Basically I need to get the part that is enclosed in the

```
<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
        0,03 p&#1091;&#1073;.           </span>
```

I have attempted to use HTMLAgiltiyPack, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var node = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee']");

var text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.InnerText);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I was just using Market_listing_price instead of the full deal. I will check it when I get home from work. Thank you.

Comment: After getting home and firing this up, I am still getting an Object Reference error. I have changed it from SelectSingleNode to a foreach and SelectNodes since there are multiple nodes with that same span, all reporting a different value. It appears to not be finding the span, and returning null.

Comment: I have figured out the issue. It was how I was loading the html. I didn't realize I needed to create a HttpWebRequest and deal with it accordingly before passing it into the HtmlDocument.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you cannot just put a URL into the doc.LoadHtml. You have to use a HttpWebRequest and Response.